# Mystery characters appear when I use insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend" ... to add an element to the DOM

Tags: javascript, php, html, dom

I'm relatively new to javascript and php and I have been doctoring around with this problem for hours with no success.

I am creating a list on a webpage where the list items are retrieved from a database. The php code for the list creation looks like this:

```
$options = get_option( 'psb_config' );
$n = 0;
echo '<ul id="session-type-list">';
foreach ( $options['type'] as $t ) {
    $html = '<li id="' . $t . '-field"><input id="' . $t . '-psb" type="text" class="type-btn" size="20%" value="' . $t . '" name="psb_config[type][' . $n . ']">';
    $html .= '<input type="button" class="button" value="remove" onclick="removeTypeButton(&#34' . $t . '-field&#34)"></li>';
    echo $html;
    $n++;
}
echo '</ul>';
```

Each entry in this list has text input field and a remove button with an onClick function call `onclick="removeTypeButton(&#34' . $t . '-field&#34)">`. The `removeTypeButton()` function is a simple javascript:

```
function removeTypeButton( id ) {
    document.getElementById( id ).remove();
}
```

and it works fine.

I also want the user to be able to add fields to the list and I have an Add Session Button at the end of the list which calls the following javascript function:

```
function addTypeButton( n ) {
    var node = document.getElementById("session-type-list");
    var id = '\"field-' + n + '\"';
    var html = '<li id=' + id + '>';
    html += '<input id="psb-' + n + '" type="text" class="type-btn" size="20%" placeholder="new shoot type" name="psb_config[type][' + n + ']">';
    html += '<input id="btn-' + n + '" type="button" class="button" value="remove" onClick="removeTypeButton(' + id  + ')"></li>';
    node.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
}
```

This function in general works as expected with one exception: after it inserts the text field and the remove button at the end of the `<ul>` list the HTML for the remove button becomes scrambled.

My HTML string is:

```
<input id="btn-' + n + '" type="button" class="button" value="remove" onClick="removeTypeButton(' + id  + ')"></li>
```

and when I inspect the element in the browser the string looks like this:

```
<input id="btn-10" type="button" class="button" value="remove" onclick="removeTypeButton(" field-10")"="">
```

The `removeTypeButton(" field-10")"="">` argument is screwed up! There are additional quotation marks and an equal sign.

I've been trying to escape the quotation marks and other shenanigans including jQuery but with no success. It appears that the string is interpreted as if the onClick function ends after the `(` and the argument is interpreted as another tag.

So my question is: what am I doing wrong? I've been googling this for hours and stackoverflow is my last resort.

Any tips are highly appreciated.

Comment: What happens if you switch it around in your JS, where you set the id in your add function `var id = '\"field-' + n + '\"';` change that to `var id = "\'field-" + n + "\'";`

Comment: Thank you! That's what I tried before and it didn't work. The solution from @rjdown below works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you view the page source, rather than inspecting the element, you'll find it ends up like this

`onClick="removeTypeButton("field-10")">`

The double quotes within the double quotes is likely confusing the browser. Convert the inner quotes to singles.

`var id = '\'field-' + n + '\'';`

This should have the desired effect:

`onClick="removeTypeButton('field-10')">`